# Get world_matrix at frame for hidden object

Tags: python

Is there a way to evaluate the matrix at a given frame for hidden objects?
In the GUI I see the pos/rot/scale update but not when using the api.

For example if I animate the default Cube over a number of frames and run this all values are the same.

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects.get("Cube")
obj.hide_viewport = True

for frame in range(1,250):
    scene.frame_set(frame)
    mat = obj.matrix_world
    pos, rot, scale = mat.decompose()
    print(pos)
```

I tried adding `context.view_layer.update()` but it didn't make a difference.

One possible workaround would be to create an Empty object and apply a "Copy Transforms" constraint, but I guess there's a better way?

*I need to keep the objects hidden due to speed.

Comment: an object's transformation matrix won't update automatically for hidden objects when changing frame via `scene.frame_set()`, because updates are optimized for visible objects only to avoid unnecessary calculations. Any reason why you have to set it to hidden? Workaround you could set `obj.hide_viewport = False` and then execute loop and then after set it back to `obj.hide_viewport = True` to force updates.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie The reason for hiding is optimization, so I think your solution breaks the optimization. At first it seems contradictory as the optimization is the culprit here, but ideally you would control what is optimized (no need to display the entire object just to get the transformation matrix). So one solution is to have a visible empty parented to whatever the cube is parented to, and have the cube parented to the empty. Then the cube's local transformation matrix is the default matrix, and the world matrix matches the empty's world matrix.

Comment: Yeah I realized later I posted comment that he wanted them hidden.

Comment: The reason for hiding in viewport is that I'm writing an exporter that loops over each frame in the scene. If the object is a "streaming mesh", i.e smoke vdb object or other heavy mesh the export is very slow. If I hide it from the viewport it's very fast. It's strange that the matrix doesn't update correctly, becuse if I use the "copy transform" workaround I posted I get the correct matrix on that locator.

Comment: @SimonBjörk the reason for that is the depsgraph evaluates visible objects, and one of them is the object with the copy transform, and so the depsgraph follows the dependency. Your invisible object would also be evaluated if it was used e.g. by geometry nodes (but then I imagine it would be slower, because geometry nodes also use the mesh data and that's the thing you want to optimize…)

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady. I guess I'll go with that approach then. Seems a bit hacky, but it should work.